Will a living retaining wall live?
My idea is to grow a living fence for dogs or livestock from cut branches, and use it to shore up a hugelkultur mound south of it. Would this theoretically work? I know you don't want 'air bark' to get wet too much, that's my greatest worry, but I do live in a place with 0% humidity about half the year. My hope is it would develop root bark wherever it might get damp. Here's a quick illustration


More details please and a picture

I linked a picture, is there a way I could embed it? What more kind of details would be useful?

Where are you located, picture of the place where want the wall, how tall should the wall be. How long should it be? Tell us about slope and drainage and will you be doing the work by hand or can you rent machinery

@Ati Really cool idea. I would also like a location, I think you will need to choose your plants carefully.
